# New Ubuntu PC Build gets stuck on boot up

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, computer-building

I'm just after installing Ubuntu 22.04.1 on my new PC. That all went fine and at the end of installation it prompted me to restart the system, so I clicked restart.

But as the system was rebooting, it got stuck on the below shown screen.

[Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eumYv.jpg)

The final line being:

audit: type=1400 audit(1675386312.327.39): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" profile="/usr/sbin/cups-browsed" pid=987 comm="cups-browsed" capability=23 capname="sys_name"

As this wasn't making any progress, I was forced to hold the power button down and shut off the system hoping that everything would work fine when I started it again.

But no, I'm getting the exact same thing.

My graphics card is a Nvidia Rtx 3060, if it's relevant.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Cups is to do with printing. Are there any printers attached to the machine?

Comment: No, I don't have any printer attached

Comment: The graphis is very relevant indeed. Hopefully you selected th3e option to install 3rd party drivers, etc. Now the easy way is to disable Secure Boot in UEFI. If not then you must boot with `nomodeset` and use MOKutil to sign the drivers.